# MIgrating data from Datastore to a csv file with Dataflow in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I would like to write a pipeline to migrate some data from datastore and export it into a csv.
For that reason I was thinking about doing:

- read from datastore
- convert entities into a python dictionary (not sure about the correctness)
- write to big query
- export from big query into csv

I wrote this code but I'm not sure if my idea is correct and also I'm not sure what I exactly need to write in the last step. Instead there's any direct way to get a csv from Datastore?

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.cloud.datastore import query as datastore_query
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.BigQueryDisposition import CREATE_IF_NEEDED
from apache_beam.io.BigQueryDisposition import WRITE_TRUNCATE

def proto_to_dict(proto_obj):
    key_list = proto_obj.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name.keys()
    d = {}
    for key in key_list:
        d[key] = getattr(proto_obj, key)
    return d

p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
ds_client = datastore.Client(project=project)
query = ds_client.query(kind=kind)
query = datastore_query._pb_from_query(query)

input = p | 'ReadFromDatastore' >> ReadFromDatastore(project=project, query=query)



pipeline = (
    input
        | 'convert to dict' >> beam.Pardo(proto_to_dict())
        | 'write to big query' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                            table_spec,
                                            schema=table_schema,
                                            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,                                       create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        | 'export big query as csv' >> #i need to add the correct code
)

output = pipeline |beam.Map(print)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a CSV you should write to Cloud Storage. There is no need to use BigQuery.

Use a PTransform to convert your DataStore retrieved data, consider using a python library like csv to properly escape quotes (any string data may contain comma's that will mess up your CSV file).

Comment: I have already convert my datastore data and do you know if there's any function that I can use to write on cloud storage? I have read the documentation and some tutorial but they are always uploading the converted data directly into Big query.

Comment: Take a look here: https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.textio.html
And here for a use case (different origin) writing to GCS:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-to-gcs?#code-sample

Answer (score 0):

No need to `Dataflow` in this case.

There is no functionality to directly export `datastore` data to `CSV` file.

A possible workaround you may follow is:

- [Export the specific kind data](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#exporting_specific_kinds_or_namespaces) to a `Cloud Storage` bucket with the following gcloud command

```bash
gcloud datastore export --kinds="KIND" gs://your_bucket
```

- [Import your Datastore export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore) into BigQuery, example with `bq` command

```bash
bq --location=US load \
--source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP \
mydataset.book_data \
gs://mybucket/20180228T1256/default_namespace/kind_Book/default_namespace_kind_Book.export_metadata
```

- [Export the BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in) table as a csv file, example with `bq` command :

```bash
bq extract \
--compression GZIP \
'mydataset.mytable' \
gs://example-bucket/myfile.csv
```

These steps can be automated in a `shell` script if you have to automate this process.

`Dataflow` is more used if you have business rules and transformations to apply on your data. This does not seem to be the case for you.